# How to filter questions with more than one criteria?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, filtering

I would like to know if there is a way to filter questions with two or more criterias, for example:

1. Featured and
2. Unanswered

Thanks!

Comment: [Search for bounties (from an answer on MSE)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200242/280467), then just add `answers:0` to that.